# Android default click sound (audio file)

Tags: android

I would like to play default Android click sound in my application, even on non-Android systems. Where can I obtain this audio file on my device (Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0), or where can I download this audio file from the web?

Comment: The Android Source code is available on Google Code or on Github. https://github.com/android/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* its this file:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/sounds/effects/Effect_Tick.ogg

But I can't check right now. But it should be in this directory for sure:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/sounds/